# Background-image jumps 1px on hover in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover

There's this odd IE issue that has been twisting my mind. It works correct in other browsers (Chrome / Firefox).

For those that want to dive directly in the code, here's [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JgWzF/1/). Important parts:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn">MyButton</a>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
    display:block; width:135px; height:58px; text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image:url("http://i47.tinypic.com/e7f4w6.png");
}

.btn:hover { background-position:bottom; }
```

In the Fiddle I've added an arrow to display the correct "center" of the image. As you can see, this is just a simple **image sprite** for navigation. The height of the image is double the height of the actual button, so we can apply the `background-position:bottom` .

But for some reason, when hovering, IE doesn't display the image correctly. Somehow the arrow (black line) and the center line (red line in the hover state) don't align anymore:

Normal state:
[image: Normal state]

Hover state:
[image: Hover state]

Because the line "jumps", the text also jumps (hardly noticeable in my example, but on my project you see it pretty good). Tested & occurs with IE9 and below on Win7.

I hope you might have a solution for this little brain teaser!

Comment: Your fiddle works fine in IE9, Win7

Comment: Your fiddle works fine in IE8, WinXP

Comment: Working fine in IE7/8 on WinXP.

Comment: Does your HTML and CSS validate without errors? (http://validator.w3.org/ and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: MarcoK - Does the error occur for you when you view it in IE from your jsfiddle? If not and it's only appearing on your local machine are you using a css reset file to get rid of all padding/margins etc first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments from jQuerybeast, Miguel-F & Billy Moat above pushed me to another direction (thanks folks!), and I tried to open my Fiddle on another machine. Same browser, same OS & **it was working fine**.

After some further investigation, I found out it was my screen resolution and/or video display and/or taskbar that caused the strange effect. This would mean my code is correct, but somehow IE draws some pixels wrong on the screen (where other browsers do this correct). But this might be a whole new question.

Once again, thanks for the help!